# If $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_na_n $ converges when $x_n\to 0,$ then $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n $ also converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence with non negative terms so that for every sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $x_n \geq 0$ and $\lim_nx_n=0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_na_n$ converges. Show that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n $ also converges.

We can proceed through contradiction by assuming $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = \infty$ and then constructing a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_na_n $ diverges.

Comment: So proceed by constructing such a sequence. What have you tried?

Comment: This is false: $x_n = a_n = 1/n$.

Comment: I take it the assumption should hold for all sequences $x_n$ and have reworded the question to make this more clear. Under this assumption, $a_n=1/n$ is no longer a counterexample since the sum $\sum x_na_n$ can be made to diverge.

Comment: This was asked before on the site.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577036/if-sum-a-nb-n-converges-for-each-null-sequence-b-n-then-sum-a-n-is-abs

Answer (score 9):

If $\sum a_n=\infty$, there is an infinite sequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=n_{k-1}+1}^{n_k} a_n > 1$ for all $k$. Define $x_n=\frac{1}{k}$, where $n_{k-1} < n \leq n_k$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll follow the poster's suggestion of assuming that the sum $\sum_n a_n=\infty$, and then construct a sequence $x_n$ so that $\sum_n x_na_n=\infty$.

We can assume without loss of generality that $a_n>0$ since we can otherwise just ignore those $n$ for which $a_n=0$.

Let $A_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$ with $A_0=0$. By assumption, $A_n\rightarrow\infty$, and therefore so does $B_n=\sqrt{A_n}$. Then, the differences $b_n=B_n-B_{n-1}$ will also be positive with $\sum_n b_n=\infty$.

We now let $x_n=b_n/a_n$. This satisfies $x_n\approx 1/2\sqrt{A_n}$: i.e., the derivative of the square root transformation used to make $B_n$ from $A_n$. More precisely,
$$
b_n=\sqrt{A_n}-\sqrt{A_{n-1}}
=\frac{A_n-A_{n-1}}{\sqrt{A_n}+\sqrt{A_{n-1}}}
=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{A_n}+\sqrt{A_{n-1}}}
$$
so that
$$
x_n=\frac{b_n}{a_n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{A_n}+\sqrt{A_{n-1}}}.
$$

Since $A_n$ is strictly increasing towards infinity, $x_n$ will thus decrease towards zero and satisfy the requirements. However, $\sum_n x_na_n=\sum_n b_n=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

No! suppose $a_n=1$ and $x_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx_n$ is convergent and $x_n\rightarrow 0$ but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Comment: read the comments on the initial post; the statement is that it should work for *any* $x_n\to 0$