# An exercise about sequences and series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_n$ be a sequence with the  property that whenever the sequence $b_n \longrightarrow 0$ ,the series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n < \infty $.
Prove that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n| < \infty$

Can someone give me a hint for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For a proof by contradiction, use $b_n=\mathrm{sign}(a_n)/s_n$ where $s_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n|a_k|$, as indicated [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/388898/).

Comment: does bn converges to zero?

Comment: @SimpleArt What? Let me suggest to slow down a notch and to try to actually understand what is written before posting comments such as the preceding one. To be proven: If $(a_n)$ is such that for every $(b_n)$ such that $P$ holds then $Q$ holds, then $R$ holds. Proof suggested in my comment: Let $(a_n)$ such that $R$ does not hold, then there exists $(b_n)$ such that $P$ holds and $Q$ does not hold. Clearer now?

Comment: capo: Same remark as in the comment above.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Did

Comment: @Did I'm still missing the same thing than [capo](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/359315/capo).You suppose that $R$ does not hold by contradiction. I'm OK here. Then why for $b_n=\mathrm{sign}(a_n)/s_n$, $P$ holds? I imagine that $P \equiv b_n \longrightarrow 0$, right?

Comment: @Did why do we derive a contradiction with the sequence bn you indicated above?

Comment: Using Did's hint, the result is immediate upon appealing to the result [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388898/if-the-positive-series-sum-a-n-diverges-and-s-n-sum-limits-k-leqslant-na)

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Right.

Comment: @capo Here is a crazy idea: do a tiny little part yourself. At present you have been indicated a full proof, at least tell us how far you went with it (otherwise we might start to have bad ideas about the way you use the site...).

Comment: @Did I should have gone to bed earlier yesterday evening...

Comment: @Did check my other questions and then start talking..Also yesterday i did not have the time to think about it.Thank you very much

Comment: "check my other questions and then start talking" Excellent.