# Mean Value theorem problem?(inequality)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, logarithms

I'm trying to solve this mean value theorem problem but confused where to start,

> If $0<a<b$ prove that $(1-\frac{a}{b})<\ln\frac{b}{a}<\frac{b}{a}-1$

Can someone please lend me a hand?

Comment: See also: [Intuition behind logarithm inequality: $1 - \frac1x \leq \log x \leq x-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324345), [Showing $\frac{x}{1+x}<\log(1+x)<x$ for all $x>0$ using the mean value theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/652581). (And other posts linked there.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the mean value theorem to the function $x\mapsto \ln x$  on the interval $[a,b]$: $\exists c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$1-\frac b a=\frac {b-a} b<\ln b-\ln a=\ln \frac{b} {a}=(b-a)\frac 1 c<\frac {b-a} a=\frac b a-1$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT :
$$1-\frac ab\lt \ln b-\ln a\lt \frac ba -1$$
$$\iff \frac{1-\frac ab}{b-a}\lt\frac{\ln b-\ln a}{b-a}\lt\frac{\frac ba -1}{b-a}$$
$$\iff \frac{b-a}{b(b-a)}\lt \frac{\ln b-\ln a}{b-a}\lt\frac{b-a}{a(b-a)}$$