# Prove inequality using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality

I'm trying to prove

$1 - \frac{a}{b} \leq \ln\frac{b}{a}\leq\frac{a}{b} - 1$ where $0 < a < b$
using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem.

Applying the theorem to $\ln x$ results in:
$$\exists\epsilon\in(a,b): \ln'(\epsilon)(b-a)=\ln b - \ln a$$
$$\frac{b}{\epsilon}-\frac{a}{\epsilon}=\ln \frac{b}{a}$$

This looks very similar to the target inequality (set $\epsilon=a$ and $\epsilon=b$), but I'm not sure how to get to it.

**Edit:**
Looks like my question is an exact duplicate of [Mean Value theorem problem?(inequality)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618525/mean-value-theorem-probleminequality), The answer doesn't really explain how to get to the inequalities though.

Comment: Looks like a clear duplicate to me. What are you missing in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/618533/42969?

Comment: @MartinR How they get to the inequalities: why is $\frac{b-a}{b} < \ln b - \ln a$?

Comment: $ \ln b - \ln a = \frac{b-a}{c} > \frac{b-a}{b}$  because $a < c < b$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I understand it now, thanks to both you and the answers I got on this question.

Comment: @ToddSewell If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi Well this question was closed as a duplicate so presumably it's already solved.

Comment: @ToddSewell You are right even if I didn't see the other answer when I've posted mine, anyway Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that fro MVT

$$\ln b - \ln a=\ln \frac{b}a=\frac{b-a}{c} \quad c\in(a,b)$$

and varing $c$ between $a$ and $b$

$$1-\frac{a}{b}\leq\frac{b-a}{c}\leq \frac{b}{a}-1$$

thus

$$1-\frac{a}{b}\leq\ln \frac{b}a\leq \frac{b}{a}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\frac{\ln(b)-\ln(a)}{b-a}=\frac{1}{\xi}$$ and $$\xi \in (a,b)$$
it is not difficult to complete this, since we have $$0<a<b$$ we get that $$\frac{1}{\xi}<\frac{1}{a}$$ and $$\frac{1}{\xi}>\frac{1}{b}$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/933693)

Comment: and why is it so like you say?

Comment: OP already has that equality written in the question. The question is how to find the inequalities from that equality, and your answer doesn't really adress that.

Comment: now it does i think