# how to prove that $\ln(1+x)< x$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I want to prove that: $\ln(x+1)< x$.

My idea is to define:  $f(x) = \ln(x+1) - x$, so:

$f'(x) = \dfrac1{1+x} - 1  = \dfrac{-x}{1+x} < 0, \text{ for }x >0$.

Which leads to $f(x)<f(0)$, so $\ln (x+1)-x<0$.

Is that a valid proof?
Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: For which $x$ do you want to prove the inequality? $\ln(1+x)$ is not defined for $x\le -1$, the inequality is false for $x=0$.

Comment: i'm not  sure. if it's for $x>0$ so i guess what i did is valid. but if it's for $x>-1$ so how can i proceed?

Comment: For lots of ideas, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex

Comment: You just have to integrate a part that says $f(0)\leq\ 0$

Comment: For $x=0$ it's not true: $\text{LHS} = \ln 1 = 0$ and $\text{RHS}=0$ so $\text{LHS} < \text{RHS}$ is false.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324345/intuition-behind-logarithm-inequality-1-frac1x-leq-log-x-leq-x-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach is correct but you need to add some more details. Based on your approach let $f(x) = \log(1 + x) - x$ so that $f(0) = 0$. Clearly $$f'(x) = -\frac{x}{1 + x}$$ and hence $f'(x) > 0$ if $-1 < x < 0$ and $f'(x) < 0$ if $x > 0$. It follows that that $f(x)$ in increasing in $(-1, 0]$ and decreasing in $[0, \infty)$. Thus we have $f(x) < f(0)$ if $-1 < x < 0$ and $f(x) < f(0)$ if $x > 0$. It thus follows that $f(x) \leq f(0) = 0$ for all $x > -1$ and there is equality only when $x = 0$. So we can write $$\log(1 + x) \leq x$$ for all $x > -1$ and there is equality only when $x = 0$.

**Note**: We have considered $x > -1$ because $\log(1 + x)$ is not defined if $x \leq -1$.

Answer (score 6):

Another proof is based on the fact that $e^x$ is a convex function and $x+1$ is tangent to $e^x$ at $0$. That is,

$$x+1< e^x, \text{ if } x\not =0, \text { and } x+1=e^x \text{ if } x=0.$$

Taking the natural logarithm of both sides we get that

$$\ln(x+1)< x \text { if } x\not =0.$$

Comment: what's a convex function ?

Comment: $f(x)$ is convex if for any pairs of $x_1<x_2$ for the straight line $y(x)$ going through the points $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ $f(x)<y(x)$ if $x_1<x<x_2$. If the straight line is tangent to such a convex  function then $f(x)\ge y(x)$ .$.

Answer (score 6):

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{6}+ \cdots > 1+x$$

if $x>0$. Then, taking the logarithm, which is an increasing function, we get $x > \ln(1+x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we are working on $x>0
 $ we have $$\log\left(x+1\right)<x\Leftrightarrow x+1<e^{x}\Leftrightarrow x+1<\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\Leftrightarrow1<\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}
 $$ and this is true because $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}=1+\sum_{k\geq2}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}.$$ Note that for $x=0$ the inequality fails.

Comment: Thanks, and if we are working on $x>-1$?

Answer (score 0):

I think it does work for $x>0$, but also it works for $x > -1$. Notice that $f'$ tells you that $f$ has an absolute maximum at $x=0$ and so $f(x) \leq f(0)=0$ for all $x>-1$.

Comment: Why it tells me that $f$ has an absolute maximum at $x=0$?