# Proof |1/cosh(x)|≥|ln(cosh(x)/(1+cosh(x))|

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, absolute-value, hyperbolic-functions

I am doing a problem where I need to prove that $$\left|\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}\right|≥\left|\ln\left(\frac{\cosh(x)}{1+\cosh(x)}\right)\right|$$
Without differentiation, and I can't find a way to prove it. Can anyone prove it without

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 
$$
\ln (1+x) \le x \text { for } x > -1
$$ (see for example [how to prove that $\ln(1+x)< x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376462/how-to-prove-that-ln1x-x)) the following holds for $y = \cosh x \ge 1$:
$$
\left\lvert\ln \frac{y}{1+y}\right\rvert = - \ln \frac{y}{1+y} = \ln \frac{1+y}{y} \le \frac 1y
$$

Comment: I don't see how your conclusion follows from ln(1+x)≤x for x>-1. can you elaborate?

Comment: @McRaylie: $\ln \frac{1+y}{y} = \ln \left( 1 + \frac 1y \right) \le \frac 1y$.