# Can We Use $\log(1+x/y) \leq x/y$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I want to know that can we have the following inequality for $x>0$, $y>0$?

$$\log(1+x/y) \leq x/y$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1376462/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/652581/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324345/42969 ... all of them with links to more duplicate questions

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

It follows from 
$$e^t\ge 1+t $$
for all $t\in\Bbb R$ (with equality iff $t=0$).

Comment: I wonder how he get 3 upvotes and he has no justification for what is saying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Write $t=x/y>0$ and $f(t) = t-\log(1+t)$, then $f(0) = 0$ and $$f'(t) = 1-{1\over 1+t} = {t\over 1+t} >0$$

So $f$ is increasing, so for every $t>0$ we have $f(t)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)=t-\ln(1+t),$ where $t>0$.

Thus, $$f'(t)=1-\frac{1}{1+t}=\frac{t}{1+t}>0,$$ which says $$f(t)>f(0)=0.$$

For $t=\frac{x}{y}$ we obtain:
$$\frac{x}{y}>\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{y}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Know that for $x>y$, the inequality holds and is strict. For $x<y$, let's expand $\log(1+\frac{x}{y})$ around $x\approx 0$,

$
\log(1+\frac{x}{y}) \approx \frac{x}{y} - \frac{x^2}{2y^2} + \frac{x^3}{3y^3} - \frac{x^4}{4y^4} + \dots
$

Now, since $\frac{x^2}{2y^2} > \frac{x^3}{3y^3}$, we are adding a negative number to $\frac{x}{y}$ in the above expression. So, $\exists$ some $\Delta>0$ such that

$
\log(1+\frac{x}{y}) \leq \frac{x}{y} - \Delta.
$