# Bound the probability - $P(|1 - e^{-(x - y)}| \geq \delta) $ if $P(|x-y| \geq \epsilon) \leq \kappa $.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, inequality, probability-distributions

Is the quantity $|1 - e^{-(x - y)}|$ bounded if $|x-y|$ is bounded? 
I think answer is obviously yes. But can we bound the following probability - $P(|1 - e^{-(x - y)}| \geq \delta) $ if $P(|x-y| \geq \epsilon)  \leq \kappa $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are interested in $0<\delta<1$, we have
$$P(|1-e^{y-x}|\le\delta)=P\left(\ln(1-\delta)\le y-x\le \ln(1+\delta) \right)\\
\ge P\left(-\delta\le y-x\le \frac\delta{1+\delta} \right)\\
\ge P\left(|y-x|\le \frac\delta{1+\delta} \right),
$$
where I have used the second set of inequalities given in [Intuition behind logarithm inequality: $1 - \frac1x \leq \log x \leq x-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324345).

Now if $P(|x-y|\le \epsilon)\ge 1-\kappa_\epsilon$, we get
$$P(|1-e^{y-x}|\le\delta)\ge 1-\kappa_{\delta/(1+\delta)}.$$