# Show that $(1+x)^{(1+x)}>e^x$

Tags: analysis, inequality

How can I prove that $(1+x)^{(1+x)}>e^x$ for all $x>0$?

The problem arose as I tried to prove the well-known & intuitive econometric principle that the more often you compound your interest, the more interest you ultimately get (in maths, that $\frac{d}{dn}((1+\frac{1}{n})^n)>0$ for $n>0$).

An interesting further problem is to prove that $(a+x)^{(a+x)}>e^x$ is true for all $x>0$ if and only if $a\geq1$.

Comment: Take the logarithm of both sides, which results in  $log(x+1)\gt \frac{x}{x+1}$. Then use the inequalities proven here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324345/intuition-behind-logarithm-inequality-1-frac1x-leq-log-x-leq-x-1

Comment: $\displaystyle ~(0.9+x)^{0.9+x} \gg e^x ~$ for $~x:=2~$

Answer (score 6):

First, observe that
\begin{align}
&(1 + x)^{(1 + x)} > e^x
\\&\iff (1 + x) \log (1 + x) > x
\\&\iff (1 + x)\log(1 + x) - x > 0
\end{align}
Set $f(x) = (1 + x)\log(1 + x) - x$. Then
$$
f'(x) = \log(1 + x) + 1 - 1 = \log(1 + x)
$$
So $f'(x) > 0$ whenever $x > 0$. That is, $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$. On the other hand
$$
f(0) = (1 + 0) \log(1 + 0) - 0 = 0
$$
These two facts together show that $f(x) > 0$ whenever $x > 0$, which is equivalent to what needed to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: apply $\ln$ to both sides of the inequality.

$$(1+x)\ln(1+x) > x\Rightarrow (1+x)\ln(1+x) - x > 0$$

The proof for $x \geq e-1$ is straightforward. 
For $0 < x < e-1$, by the concept of derivative show that it is increasing in the specified area.

Answer (score 2):

Most such inequalities seem to follow from the [familiar result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504663) that $e^t > 1 + t$ for all real $t \ne 0$.

In this case, putting $t = -\log(1 + x)$:
$$
(1 + x)\log(1 + x) = e^{-t}(-t) > e^{-t}(1 - e^t) = e^{-t} - 1 = x \quad (x > -1,\ x \ne 0).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your general case is easy with this corollary of the *Mean value theorem*:

> Let $f,g$ be two differentiable functions defined on an interval $I$ and $x_0\in I$.
>
> If $f(x_0)\ge g(x_0)$ and $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x>x_0,\:x\in I$, then  $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x>x_0,\:x\in I$.

Indeed it is enough to compare the logs: set $f_a(x)=(a+x)\ln(a+x)$, $g(x)=x$. We have $f(0)=a\ln a\ge g(0)=0$ iff $a\ge 1$.

Now compare the derivatives:

$f'_a(x)=\ln(a+x)+1>1$ for all $x>0\iff a+x>1$ for all $x>0 \iff a\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(1+x)^{1+x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^4}{3} + \cdots
$$
is clearly greater than
$$
e^{x} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \cdots
$$
for $x > 0.$