# How to show that $a_n = (1+\frac12)(1+\frac14)\cdots(1+\frac1{2^n})$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

How do I show, using only basic methods, that a product
$$a_n=(1+{1 \over 2}) \cdot (1+{1 \over 4}) \cdot ... \cdot(1+{1 \over 2^n})$$
converges?

I know, that $a_1 = {3\over2}$, and that $a_{n+1} = a_n \cdot (1+ {1 \over 2^{n+1}})$.

Going further:
$$ {{a_{n+1}}\over{a_n}} = 1+ {1 \over 2^{n+1}} > 1$$

Now I can prove by induction, that $a_n$ is monotonically increasing, and is greater than one.

Now, I want to prove, that $a_n$ is convergent. How can I do this? I can't seem to find any sequence greater than $a_n$ with a limit other than + infinity.

Edit
Following @Barry Cipra comment, i tried taking $ln(a_n)$, so:
$$ ln(a_n) = ln((1+{1 \over 2}) \cdot (1+{1 \over 4}) \cdot ... \cdot(1+{1 \over 2^n}))$$
$$ ln(a_n) = ln(1+{1 \over 2}) + ln(1+{1 \over 4}) + ... +ln(1+{1 \over 2^n})$$
$$ ln(a_n) < 1+{1 \over 2}+1+ {1 \over 4}+...+1+{1 \over 2^n} = n +1$$
$$ ln(a_n) < n+1 $$
$$ a_n < e^{n+1} $$

But I still don't know how this gets me any closer to the answer

Comment: Try looking at $\log a_n$ and use the fact that $\log(1+x)\approx x$ for small $x$.

Comment: @BarryCipra updated the question with your method

Answer (score 2):

It is true that $\ln (x)\le x$ for every $x$, but a [sharper inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324345/215011) is:
$$
\ln (x) \le x-1\qquad{\text{for all $x$}}.
$$
Using this inequality you get
$$\ln (a_n) \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{2^k}\le 1,
$$
which implies that $(a_n)$ is bounded above. From this, along with what you've already established, we deduce that $(a_n)$ converges.