# Bound $\frac{\ln\left(\frac{c}{\ln\left(n\right)}\right)}{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{c}\right)+\frac{1}{c}}$ where $2\leq c < \ln\left(n\right)$

Tags: approximation, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to prove an approximation ratio of an algorithm. I am trying to find an upper bound to $$\frac{\ln\left(\frac{c}{\ln\left(n\right)}\right)}{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{c}\right)+\frac{1}{c}}$$ where $2\leq c < \ln\left(n\right)$.

Both the numerator and the denominator are negative. The numerator is negative since $\frac{c}{\ln\left(n\right)}<1$ because $c<\ln\left(n\right)$. The denominator is negative since $\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{c}\right)<-\frac{1}{c}$.

If we set $n$ to be 1e6, the expression looks like:
[image]

I tried to use the [partial derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdc%20ln%28c%2Fln%28n%29%29%2F%28ln%281-1%2Fc%29%2B1%2Fc%29), but I'm failing to isolate $c$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{c}{\ln\left(n\right)}\right)}{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{c}\right)+\frac{1}{c}}\right)=\frac{\left(c-1\right)\left(c\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{c}\right)+1\right)-\ln\left(\frac{c}{\ln\left(n\right)}\right)}{\left(c-1\right)\left(c\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{c}\right)+1\right)^2}$$

Another alternative is to bound the expression by $c\ln\left(\frac{n}{\ln\left(n\right)}\right)$, where $2\leq c < \ln\left(n\right)$:
$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac{c}{\ln\left(n\right)}\right)}{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{c}\right)+\frac{1}{c}}<c\ln\left(\frac{n}{\ln\left(n\right)}\right)$$

I tend to believe that the last inequality is correct based on several examples ([$n=1e5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20ln%28c%2Fln%281e5%29%29%2F%28ln%281-1%2Fc%29%2B1%2Fc%29%2C%20c*ln%281e5%2Fln%281e5%29%29%20for%20c%3D2%20to%20ln%281e5%29), [$n=1e6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20ln%28c%2Fln%281e6%29%29%2F%28ln%281-1%2Fc%29%2B1%2Fc%29%2C%20c*ln%281e6%2Fln%281e6%29%29%20for%20c%3D2%20to%20ln%281e6%29), and [$n=1e7$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20ln%28c%2Fln%281e7%29%29%2F%28ln%281-1%2Fc%29%2B1%2Fc%29%2C%20c*ln%281e7%2Fln%281e7%29%29%20for%20c%3D2%20to%20ln%281e7%29)). For $n$ equals 1e6:
[image]

Comment: Did you try the bounds here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324345/intuition-behind-logarithm-inequality-1-frac1x-leq-log-x-leq-x-1

Comment: @Explorer, I tried the first one ($1-\frac{1}{x}\leq ...$) in the denominator, but I couldn't reach a meaningful bound.