# Proof Verification: $\frac{x}{x+1} \leq \ln(x+1)$ for $x > 0$ with equality iff $x=0$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals

Proof Verification: $\frac{x}{x+1} \leq \ln(x+1)$ for $x > -1$ with equality iff $x=0$

**My Attempt:**

We know that $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \leq \frac{1}{x+1}$, for $x > 0. $At $x=0 $ they are the same.

$$\int\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx \leq \int\frac{1}{x+1}dx$$
$$\frac{-1}{x+1} +C_1 \leq \ln(x+1) + C_2$$

We conclude that $C_1 =1, C_2 =0$ f0r the $x=0$ case from the original equality to hold.

$$\frac{-1}{x+1}+\frac{x+1}{x+1}-1 +1 \leq \ln(x+1)$$
$$\frac{x}{x+1} \leq \ln(x+1)$$

Is this approach right?

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: it looks good to me as well, but I think you might be able to get away with just saying: Look they are the same at $x=0$, and $ln(x+1)$ grows faster (take derivatives) and you are done.

Comment: The first line "$\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \leq \frac{1}{x+1}$" is false for $-1 < x < 0$ (try plugging in $x = -\frac{1}2$), so this approach will need to consider that. For an alternative approach, take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324345/intuition-behind-logarithm-inequality-1-frac1x-leq-log-x-leq-x-1

Comment: Is there a quick fix for that? Cause I need to show its true for $x>-1$ not $x>0$

Comment: Why not take the derivative of $\ln(x+1)-\frac{x}{x+1} $?  It's as simple as $x/(x+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is ok. But it is better to integrate
$$ \frac{1}{(t+1)^2} \leq \frac{1}{t+1}$$
from $0$ to $x$; namely
$$ \int_0^x\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}dt \leq \int_0^x\frac{1}{t+1}dt. $$
Then you will get the desired inequality soon instead of concluding $C_1=C_2=0$.

Comment: Why are you integrating the second one from $0$ to $1$? How do you know that inequality will hold?

Comment: This is a typo. It should be $x$ instead of 1. Thanks for pointing.