# How to evaluate the limit of this following expression $\color{black}{\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{6n}{9{n}^2-{r}^2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, contest-math

I am not able to find the limit of the following expression, after trying a bit hard:$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{6n}{9{n}^2-{r}^2}$$ Can some one help with some approach?

Comment: Use: Definite Integral and apply the limit of sum formula => https://prnt.sc/vu3x6i

Comment: @ jon I don't have that idea I only know upto _L hospital's rule_, that is why may be I am not able to do it! Can you throw some more light , i.e how to do such things?

Comment: Look at @Archis Welankar answer. He went a bit more in-depth / almost to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Taking $n^2$ common from denominator we have $\frac{6n}{9n^2-r^2}=\frac{6}{9-\frac{r^2}{n^2}}\frac{1}{n}$ . Now observing the fact that it's a Riemann sum we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_1^{n} \frac{6n}{9n^2-r^2}=\int _0^1 \frac{6}{9-x^2}dx$ .
I hope you can continue from here.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as this question is tagged as precalculus and contest math, here's a solution that avoids Riemann sums:

Write
$$
\frac{6n}{9n^2-r^2}=\frac{6n}{(3n+r)(3n-r)}=\frac1{3n+r}+\frac1{3n-r}
$$
and sum over $r=1,\ldots,n$ to find that
$$
\frac1{3n} + \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{6n}{9n^2-r^2}=\frac 1{2n} + \frac1{2n+1} +\cdots + \frac1{4n-1}+\frac1{4n}.
$$
If you're familiar with sums of the form $S_n:=\frac1{an}+\cdots+\frac1{bn}$ (for $b>a$) you know that the RHS converges to $\log (b/a)=\log 2$.

---

For completeness, here's an elementary derivation.

**Claim:** Assume $b>a$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac 1{an}+\cdots+\frac1{bn}\right) = \log\left(\frac ba\right).$$

**Proof:** Take [the inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3253689/215011)
$$
\frac{x-1}x\le \log x \le x-1
$$
and substitute $x=1+\frac1k$. This yields for every $k$
$$
\frac1{k+1}\le \log(k+1)-\log k\le \frac 1k.
$$
Sum from $k=an$ to $bn$ and use telescoping to get
$$S_n-\frac1{an}+\frac1{bn+1}\le \log(bn+1)-\log(an)\le S_n.
$$
Rearrange this to the form
$$
\log\left(\frac{bn+1}{an}\right)\le S_n\le \log\left(\frac{bn+1}{an}\right)+\frac1{an}-\frac1{bn+1}.
$$
Take the limit as $n\to\infty$ and apply the squeeze theorem to obtain the result.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @Archis Welankar's answer:

Once you've solved the *Limit of Sum* definition of the series - limit, you then simply solve for the integral.

> $ \int _0^1 \frac{6}{9-x^2}dx = \mathbf{\ln(2)}$

Comment: I've done my best to honour your make-the-answer-bold intent within MathJax.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! <3

Answer (score 1):

We can even compute the partial sums
$$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{6n}{9{n}^2-{r}^2}=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{3 n+r}+\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{3 n-r}$$
$$S_n=\big[\psi (4 n+1)-\psi (3 n+1) \big]+\big[\psi (1-3 n)-\psi (1-2 n)\big]$$ Using asymptotics
$$S_n=\log (2)+\frac{1}{24 n}+\frac{1}{64 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$