# What is reasoning behind statement that $\log \frac{3}{2} < (\frac{3}{2} - 1)$?

Tags: logarithms, approximation

In his paper, "Euler and the Partial Sums of the Prime Harmonic Series" ([pdf](http://pollack.uga.edu/eulerprime.pdf)), Paul Pollacks makes a small statement at the top of page 4:

$$ \log \frac{3}{2} < (\frac{3}{2} - 1) = \frac12 $$

I can see numerically this is true, but I can't see how he makes the inequality $\log \frac{3}{2} < (\frac{3}{2} - 1)$.

I have looked through references of power series approximations but can't see anything that matches.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324345/intuition-behind-logarithm-inequality-1-frac1x-leq-log-x-leq-x-1) for a proof of the general case.

Comment: usually written $\log (1+x) < x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x > 1$ we have
$$
\log(x) < x - 1.
$$
For a geometric proof, note that both functions vanish at $x = 1$ and that the graph of $\log(x)$ is concave down (so is trapped below the tangent line as you move to the right).

Comment: you seem to have the inequality sign backwards

Comment: @WillJagy fixed, thanks!

Comment: @hunter is there an argument to be made using the gradient of $\log(x)=1/x$ to formalise the statement that $y=\log(x)$ is always less than $y=x-1$ ?

Comment: @tariqrashid the first derivative gives the slope of the tangent line and the second derivative being negative shows that the graph is concave down.

Answer (score 1):

If $x = 1$ then $0 =\ln x = x-1$.

Would you accept that as $x, x-1$ and $\ln x$ get larger than $x$ and $x-1$ getter larger "faster" than $x$ does?

We can argue that with derivatives.

$\frac {dx}{dx} = \frac {d(x-1)}{dx} = 1$  but for $x > 1$ then $\frac {d\ln x}{dx} = \frac 1x < 1$.

So $\ln x$ increases more "slowly" than $x-1$.

So if they start on the racetrack at the same value at $x = 1$ (so $x-1 =0$ and $\ln x = 0$) but $x-1$ is always faster than $\ln x$ which just gets slower and slower, then $x-1$ immediate surpasses it.

Of course.... I have to take my roommate to the hospital as I just knocked his eye out but waving my hands about so wildly.)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check that the function

$$f(x)= x-1-\log x$$

has a minimum equal to $0$ at $x=1$ through derivative's test , so for all other points $f(x) >0$